# How to allow SonicOS SSLVPN IP Range to access a single WAN Host

Tags: sonicwall, vpn

We have a SonicWall TZ 205 W (SonicOS Enhanced 5.8.1.15-48o) Network Security Appliance.

Users from outside take an SSLVPN connection with NetExtender. They can access resources in the LAN just fine.

We have also configured a S2S VPN connection from the SonicWall to Azure Virtual network. The users of the SSLVPN have been added with this access and it works just fine.

**The Problem:**

However, we also have an SQL Azure database which we would like to route through the SSLVPN. It cannot be added to the Azure Virtual Network because Microsoft don't support this thus it needs to reside in the WAN zone.

1. We already have added the SQL Azure host's IP address to the SSLVPN client routes.
2. We already have a following `firewall access rule`:

   - **Source:** SSLVPN IP Pool
   - **Destination:** SQL Azure (Address Object: Host, Zone: WAN)
   - **Service:** Any
   - **Action:** Allow
3. Traffic statistics for this rule show 0 Tx and Rx bytes.

If the SQL Azure was behind a VPN connection, it'd be simply a matter to add the VPN access to the SSLVPN users but how do I make this SonicWall allow connections from SSLVPN IP Range to a host in the WAN Zone?

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution**

On the `Users` > `Local Groups`, configure `SSLVPN Services` group and under tab `VPN Access` add the object `WAN RemoteAccess Networks`.